# How to use pusher with laravel and vue js to create real time chat?

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I am new to laravel and I have made real time chat with laravel and vue js and with pusher. I guess everything is fine with the code, but the chat is not working real time. I need a help, just wanted to know where I am wrong in my code. Below is my code.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        //
         $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
         return new PrivateChannel('messages.' . $this->message->to);
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        $this->message->load('fromContact');

        return ["message" => $this->message];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'message';
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="composer">
    <textarea v-model="message" @keydown.enter="send" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    send(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (this.message == "") {
        return;
      }

      this.$emit("send", this.message);
      this.message = "";
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.composer textarea {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 10px;
  resize: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 6px;
}
</style>
```

Here is what I have tried. Everything works fine. I just need to refresh the page, but I want it without page refresh. I want it real time. Please let me know where my code is wrong. I do not know, I followed the online tutorial and it works fine, but I do not know where is the issue with my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to implement some [Pusher code](https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-notifications-laravel-pusher-channels)

Comment: i have installed and set up the pusher i can see my message came to my pusher account in debug console just it is now showing to the other user real time.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't subscribed your channel and didn't listen to your events in your code.

Comment: hi i would like to know what code you need so that i can edit my code and show it to you sorry i am new to all this.